# Downloading large datasets in JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, download, blob

I have a web application that has an OWIN SelfHost WebAPI backend and an AngularJS frontend.

In one particular view I want to be able to collect a ridiculously large amount of data from a server API and then (on demand, not immediately) write it to a client-side CSV file.

The unformatted binary data is about 80 kB per second or 4.6 MB per minute; I'm expecting the CSV to be a lot bigger than this, but I don't have an exact measurement yet.  *Most* uses are expected to be up to about 30 minutes (140 MB) but I'd like to support capturing as long as feasible.

At the moment I have API code to start the data capture and store this in server memory, but it quickly runs out.  So I'm looking for alternate solutions.  (I haven't written the client-side part yet, so that's more malleable.)

My first thought was to have the server write a temporary file/db to hold the data during the capture, then reload and stream it in chunks to the JS when the download was requested.  But isn't this just going to make the browser run out of memory too?

An added complication is that at the moment the server just has the "raw" data, which is sent as JSON to the JS to perform some tweaks to it before the JS formats it to CSV.  Would it be better to move this to the server side, so that the client side just downloads pre-baked CSV?  (This would be mildly annoying since it will require duplicating a small amount of code, but it's fairly straightforward.)

The server doesn't need to handle many concurrent requests (especially not of this type, though it's not impossible) but given a choice between the two I'd prefer making the client do most of the work.

I'm targeting recent browsers (mostly Chrome) so using new APIs is ok (research suggests Blob is the most appropriate, though I'm not sure if that allows client-side reformatting), though cross-compatibility is always nice.

Comment: shipping CSV from the server will be a lot lighter than shipping JSON, with all the repeated keys and quotes. https://github.com/rndme/download will let you download as big of files as the browser can support; a few hundred meg Blob should be doable on even half-way recent gear.

Comment: The JSON data is sent as multiple sibling arrays rather than as an array of objects precisely to avoid duplicating key names, so currently the JSON format is fairly similar to CSV.  But the client-side code would expand some of the data (recording a single value in multiple formats) so the *final* CSV would be larger than what was received from the server.  Or at least that was the initial plan.

Comment: you could also use gzip or zip from the server or client to reduce the size if the data is repetitive. jszip can produce zip files, which can then be downloaded. if you can get the size down to 20-30MB, you can hit dataURL-only older devices without window.URL support...

Comment: Compression is a good idea to improve performance -- the data is likely to be quite repetitive -- but I need to get it working first. :)